# How to disable a link button in gridview when clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two `LinkButton's` called Approve and Reject in my `GridView` and I want my Approve `LinkButton` to be `Disabled` when click on it. I tried the following code but it's not working.

```
protected void gvManagerTimeSheet_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)   
{
        if (e.CommandName == "ApproveRow")
        {
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
            LinkButton lnkbtn = (LinkButton)row.FindControl("lbApprove");
            lnkbtn.Enabled = false;

            int rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
            int TimeSheetId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spApproveTimeSheet ", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeSheetId", TimeSheetId);

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                GetManagerTimeSheets();
            }
         }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of `GetManagerTimeSheets` method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to Rebind the grid with disabled control, but also you need to check the status in itembound event and disable. For that you can use session or hidden field.

```
protected void rg_OnItemCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
   // your logic 
   hdFlag.value = "val" // id of the data item to hide if more than one use array
  // rebind logic for gird
}

protected void rg_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
  if(hdFlag.value == "id")
  {
    // Find the control and hide 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you haven't shown your aspx link button so i assuming that your link button is this

```
<asp:LinkButton id="linkBtn" runat="server" text="Approve"  OnClientClick="Disable(this);"/>
```

Now you should add a javascript function like this on the page::

```
<script>
function Disable(link)
{
link.disabled = result;
}
</script>
```

> Now when you click on the page your button will get disabled.

Comment: It simply disable your link button as per requirements!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 LinkButton lbApprove = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
```